# System.MissingMethodException when using propertyGrid

Tags: c#, winforms, json.net, propertygrid

I have a class

```
class PartitionTemplate
{
    public PartitionTemplate()
    {
        keepLabels = new List<string>();
        partitions = new List<partition>();
    }
    [JsonProperty("keepLabels")]
    public List<String> keepLabels { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("slot")]
    public int slot { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

my goal is to edit it with `propertyGrid` , using the following code:

```
    PartitionTemplate partiTemplate;
    //fi is FileInfo with the class as json using 
    //Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PartitionTemplate>(File.ReadAllText(partitionfile.FullName));
    PartitionTemplate.ReadOrCreatePartitonConfigurationFile(out partiTemplate, fi);
    propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = partiTemplate;
```

my problem is : 
when I try to `add` element to `keepLabels` i get the following error :

```
Exception thrown: 'System.MissingMethodException' in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Constructor on type 'System.String' not found.
```

how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because when you click the 'Add' button in the [Collection Editor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.collectioneditor.aspx) (a standard editor for the property grid) it creates a new item using a supposed public parameterless constructor, which doesn't exist on System.String (you can't do `var s = new String();`).

What you can do though, if you want to keep the keepLabels property as is, is to create a custom editor, like this:

```
// decorate the property with this custom attribute  
[Editor(typeof(StringListEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
public List<String> keepLabels { get; set; }

....

// this is the code of a custom editor class
// note CollectionEditor needs a reference to System.Design.dll
public class StringListEditor : CollectionEditor
{
    public StringListEditor(Type type)
        : base(type)
    {
    }

    // you can override the create instance and return whatever you like
    protected override object CreateInstance(Type itemType)
    {
        if (itemType == typeof(string))
            return string.Empty; // or anything else

        return base.CreateInstance(itemType);
    }
}
```